# git push origin master causing a fatal error

Tags: git, http, proxy, github

I am trying to push a project on github, but whenever I do `git push origin master`  I'm getting this error:

```
error: Couldn't resolve proxy 'kp.proxy.com' while accessing https://github.com/rabidmachine9/node-supercollider.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

**EDIT**: git version 1.7.3.1 , OS X 10.5.8, the kp.proxy.com won't work for sure, and it wasn't in my intention to use a proxy...I just don't know how to get rid of it...

please help!

Comment: You'll have much more luck with getting good answers to your question if you supply information such as: what operating system are you using? which version of git is this? have you set a proxy yourself, either through an environment variable or the `http.proxy` git config variable? can you resolve `kp.proxy.com` normally? etc.

Answer (score 7):

It seems you have configured Git to use a proxy server. But the server `kp.proxy.com` doesn't resolve (for me, at least).

Do you have a proxy set? Check `echo $http_proxy`. You can do `unset http_proxy`.

Also, check .git/config and remove the proxy or set a working one (details see [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config))

Comment: thanks I did what you suggested and now I get another error :error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed while accessing https://github.com/rabidmachine9/node-supercollider.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed

Answer (score 2):

I've just had the same issue & then found this post @ GitHub: https://github.com/blog/809-git-dumb-http-transport-to-be-turned-off-in-90-days

/dumb http!

Comment: thanks, it's not clear to me how it's related though...can you please explain? I solved the issue by deleting and cloning again...

Comment: yes, I had the same error message.  I resolved by using the git protocol instead.